# Finding the distributions for Bayesian Hierarchial Modelling

Tags: bayesian, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

If Bayesian Hierarchial Modelling deals with the equation

$$ p(\alpha,\theta|x) \propto p(x|\theta,\alpha) p(\theta|\alpha) p(\alpha)$$

Where do we get the distributions for $p(x|\theta,\alpha)$ and $p(\theta|\alpha)$? Im not sure how you use this formula in practice

Comment: If you're building the hierarchical model (i.e. you're not getting it from somewhere else), it's typical that you assume distributions, e.g. $x$ is distributed according to gamma with parameters $\theta, \alpha$ and also assume priors for these.